# View in browser

Tags: visual-studio

I am recently having this strange issue in my Visual Studio 2008 professional.

Whenever i try to 'View in browser', it opens a new tab in my visual studio itself and opens my application.  Before, it used to open my default browser and would run the application.  I checked my host file and it has my local host applied there.

Though, it's not a big issue, it's annoying that it opens a new tab in my visual studio itself.  Any one seen this behavior and any idea about how to resolve this?

Regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open any .aspx file and then select the "Browse With..." option from the File menu..  In there you can select your preferred browser.

Comment: Thanks Todd, for some reason, it was set to 'Internal Web Browser' as default.  I changed it to my preferred browser.  Solved.  Thanks again!!

Comment: if you don't mind marking this as answered I'd appreciate it :)